# Как объявить JLabel, чтобы на него можно было писать текст из любого класса программы?

Tags: java, swing

Есть объект Frame, на нем расположен JLabel. Как сделать так, чтобы писать текст на этот label можно было из любого класса в программе?

Comment: @Opppa, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

В том классе, в котором объявлен этот JLabel, добавьте метод вида `public void setLabelText(String text)`. И вызывайте его из других классов.

**Обновление**

[[@Opppa](/users/24041/opppa)](/users/24041/opppa), к сожалению, штатный телепат-предсказатель ХэшКода в отпуске. Так что придется выворачивать карманы и показывать код.

Comment: @Nofate, я так и делал не работает почему-то.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

[@Opppa](/users/24041/opppa): моя карманная Ванга говорит, что вы не запомнили в нужном месте экземпляр `Frame`, и не можете к нему доступиться.